# fully convolutional neural network FCRN problem in building net

Tags: python, deep-learning, model, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to write a net using pytorch and i'm facing some problems, i tried to debug some of the errors and still i get one.
File "/FCRN_B.py", line 39, in forward
x=torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv4(x)),(5,5))

the network is the following : [Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo6w4.png)
My code is the following one :

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        #1 input image channel,6 output channels,2x2 square convolution
        #kernel
        self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(1,32,3)
        self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(32,64,3)
        self.conv3=nn.Conv2d(64,128,3)
        self.conv4=nn.Conv2d(128,256,5)
        self.conv4=nn.Conv2d(256,256,5)
        self.conv4=nn.Conv2d(256,256,5)

        self.upsample1=nn.Upsample(scale_factor=1, mode='nearest')
        self.upsample2=nn.Upsample(scale_factor=1, mode='nearest')
        self.upsample3=nn.Upsample(scale_factor=8, mode='nearest')
        
    def forward(self,x):
        #Max pooling over a (2,2) window
        x = torch.squeeze(x,1)
        x=F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x=torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)),(3,3))
        x=F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x=torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv4(x)),(5,5))
        x=F.relu(F.conv2d(self.upsample1(x)))
        x=F.relu(F.conv2d(self.upsample2(x)))
        x=F.relu(F.conv2d(self.upsample1(x)))
        return x
```

net = Net()

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have four networks that are named the same. Change the name and it should work.

> 

```html
self.conv4=nn.Conv2d(128,256,5)
self.conv5=nn.Conv2d(256,256,5)
self.conv6=nn.Conv2d(256,256,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `conv4` 4 times to define different layers. In the end that made input mismatch issues. I would easily fix it like this

```
self.conv4=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128,256,5),
            nn.Conv2d(256,256,5),
            nn.Conv2d(256,256,5)
        )
```

Assuming you were using those `conv4` to denote a logical group of convolutions which achieve an unit of operation. For the sake of readability, this is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked for me, but i get another error related to upsampling and Rely..  
 conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)